# Magento2.1.0 Order Grid not displaying Search and Filter option in Admin

Tags: order-grid, magento2.1.0

I recently have upgraded the Magento2.0.7 to Magento2.1.0, once after upgrade, **i couldn't able to see the Filter and search section in admin order grids** other modules like products are having filters. Anyone came across this issue.

Comment: I ran into same issue did you get the solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have cleared cache and ran Static content deploy again then it started to work.